# MVC GUI Design - IOException in Model?

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, javafx

I am coding a GUI using the MVC (model, view, controller) design with JavaFX.

The first thing my program does is read data from a text file, which in turn may or may not throw an IOException which I want to display as an error message dialogue in the GUI through the view class.

Going by the MVC design, I know must read the file in the model class, but the model class is not allowed to interact (or even know about) the view class. So how can I pass the exception along to the view class to display under MVC?

Currently I am reading the file from the controller class and passing exceptions to the view class (controller can interact with view), but this is breaking the purpose of the controller which should only be used for handling events and changing the view accordingly.

So what are my options here? I want to avoid breaking the MVC design as much as possible!

Comment: In general, if a method may throw a checked exception, but doesn't know what to do with it, it should just throw it to the caller. So it the model has a method (or constructor) that may throw an IO exception, that method would just typically declare `throws IOException`. You presumably invoke this model method from the controller in response to some user action, so the controller can use a try-catch and change the view to display an error message. There seems to be no violation of MVC if you just follow the usual exception handling process.

Comment: @James_D Ah yes, I would think the same thing, but the implementation of the constructor for the model class is set in stone, that is, I cannot change the implementation of the construct and declare that it throws exceptions. That is why I was going down the path of a try-catch block.

Comment: Well... if you are working to a specification for the model, that specification should really include how it should behave in the event that errors occur reading the file. If that's not forthcoming, options include: 1. wrapping the IO exception in an unchecked exception, and throwing it (which really still violates the spec), 2. returning a "special value" (e.g. null instead of an empty list) which you can then handle in the controller in the same way as an exception, or 3. including a `loadException` property in the model, which you set in the catch block and check in the controller.

Comment: @James_D Thanks! I opted for your 3rd suggestion which works like a charm!